# Como validar si existen atributos dentro de la base de datos

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hola estoy creando una aplicación en **ASP.NET MVC** para clase en la que tengo que asignar un ticket a un responsable, pero para ello necesito comprobar en la base de datos si existen los parametros **category, service, priority** de la funcion **SendAsignInfo** actualizando a la persona asignada

Tengo el siguiente metodo que asigna el ticket a un responsable

```
/// <summary>
        /// Asigna un responsable a un ticket
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="userId">Matricula del responsable del ticket</param>
        /// <param name="ticket">Numero del folio del ticket</param>
        /// <param name="note">Nota de asignación escrita por el usuario</param>
        /// <param name="employeeId">A quien se le esta asignando</param>
        /// <param name="category">Categoria asignada</param>
        /// <param name="service">Servicio relacionado al ticket</param>
        /// <param name="priority">Prioridad asignada</param>
        /// <returns>Json con respuesta de la asignacion del encargado</returns>
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult SetTicketResponsable(string userId, long ticket, string note)
        {
            var notificacion = new EmailController();
            var emails = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            //obtenemos la información del solicitante y a quien esta asignado
            var applaint = TicketListModel.LastRecord(ticket);



            //TODO: que pasa si no es exitoso
            if (!applaint.Success) return Json ("invalid");

            //revisamos si es la primera vez que se le asigna a alguien
            var isFirstTime = applaint.Asigned.IsNullOrWhiteSpace();

            //actualizamos a la persona asignada
            var result = TicketListModel.SendAsignInfo(userId, employeeId, ticket, note, category, service, priority);

            //obtenemos el correo del tecnico asignado
            var ldap = new LdapController();
            var param = new[] { "mail", "name" };
            var searchResp = ldap.SearchParamsForUserById(userId, param);

            //Enviamos correo a la persona asignada
            emails.Add(searchResp.Entries[0].Attributes["mail"][0].ToString(), searchResp.Entries[0].Attributes["name"][0].ToString());
            notificacion.SendEmail(emails, "Asignación de Ticket", "Se te ha asignado un ticket");

            emails.Clear();

            if (!isFirstTime) return Json(result);

            //Enviamos correo a quien solicitó el ticket
            emails.Add(applaint.Email, applaint.Name);
            notificacion.SendEmail(emails, "Asignación de responsable", "Se ha asignado tu ticket");

            return Json(result);
        }
```

Esta es la funcion que actualiza los datos de quien esta asignado a un ticket

```
/// <param name="userId">matricula del usuario que esta llevando acabo la accion</param>
        /// <param name="employeeId">A quien se le esta asignando</param>
        /// <param name="ticket">Numero del folio del ticket</param>
        /// <param name="note">Notas por el usuario</param>
        /// <param name="category">Categoria asgianada</param>
        /// <param name="service">Servicio relacionado al ticket</param>
        /// <param name="priority">Prioridad asignada</param>
        /// <returns>Devuelve si pudo realizar la asignacion</returns>
        public static bool SendAsignInfo(string userId, string employeeId, long ticket, string note, string category, string service, string priority)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var db = new dbGoldenTicket())
                {
                    var newRecord = new TK_DT_RECORDS()
                    {
                        TK_HD_TICKETS_ID = ticket,
                        TK_BT_EMPLOYEES_ID = employeeId,
                        TK_CT_STATUS_ID = "ASG",
                        TK_CT_CATEGORIES_ID = category,
                        TK_CT_SERVICES_ID = service,
                        TK_CT_PRIORITIES_ID = priority,
                        CONTENT = "Se asigna un tecnico responsable del ticket",
                        NOTE = note,
                        USER_UPDATE = userId,
                        ACTIVITY_DATE = DateTime.Now
                    };

                    db.TK_DT_RECORDS.Add(newRecord);
                    db.SaveChanges();

                    return true;
                }
            }
```

El error al momento de realizar una asignacion con las variables declaradas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Generalmente me indica en el metodo **SendAsignInfo** que los atributos category, service, priority no existe en el contexto actual

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el error que me genera al momento de compilar por no validar si los atributos existen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como puedo validar por medio de mi metodo de accion si los atributos de category, service, priority existen ?

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96263/discussion-on-question-by-sebastian-salazar-como-validar-si-existen-atributos-de).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes declarar las variables que estas pasando al metodo

```
string category; 
string service; 
string priority;

var result = TicketListModel.SendAsignInfo(userId, employeeId, ticket, note, category, service, priority);
```

El error dice que no tienes `category, service, priority` esas variables declaradas.

Solo declararlas y obviamente las inicializas o les mandas datos y se soluciona tu error

Dando solcuion a otro error en la actualización de la pregunta cambia este metodo de la siguiente forma

```
         public static bool SendAsignInfo(string userId, string employeeId, long ticket, string note, string category, string service, string priority)
                {
                    try
                    {
                       if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(category) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(service) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(priority))
                       {
                        using (var db = new dbGoldenTicket())
                        {
                            var newRecord = new TK_DT_RECORDS()
                            {
                                TK_HD_TICKETS_ID = ticket,
                                TK_BT_EMPLOYEES_ID = employeeId,
                                TK_CT_STATUS_ID = "ASG",
                                TK_CT_CATEGORIES_ID = category,
                                TK_CT_SERVICES_ID = service,
                                TK_CT_PRIORITIES_ID = priority,
                                CONTENT = "Se asigna un tecnico responsable del ticket",
                                NOTE = note,
                                USER_UPDATE = userId,
                                ACTIVITY_DATE = DateTime.Now
                            };

                            db.TK_DT_RECORDS.Add(newRecord);
                            db.SaveChanges();

                            return true;
                        }
                      } 
                      else 
                      { 
                        return false; 
                      }
                    }
    }
```

Solo valida que los valores que llegan en las variables no sean `null`, si son `null`n debes devolver un mensjae no se advirtiendo al usuario que no se pudo asignar el ticket

Comment: agrega como se definen esas variables, ojo con los tipos

Comment: Listo, aun que no se el como tiene que enviar las variables , por eso solo las declaro.

Comment: Es que si te fijas, a la funcion que llama por post le faltan parametros.. que son esos que no estan declarados ;) creo que tiene un problema en su codigo base

Comment: Perfecto ya declara las variables pero ahora me lleva al error que esta actualizado en la pregunta

Comment: @SebastianSalazar El error que te arroja ahora quiere decir que estas enviando un valor null a una clave foranea , tienes que asegurarte que el valor que envias en esas tres variables concuerde con los valores que tienes en las tablas con las que haces referencias

Comment: Pero ya tengo un TK_CT_SERVICES_ID', dentro de TK_DT_RECORDS'; necesito hacer la validacion de que ese TK_CT_SERVICES_ID', si se encuentra en TK_DT_RECORDS';

Comment: @SebastianSalazar necesitas validar entonces que si ese id existe dentro de la tabla no deje guardar uno mas con ese mismo id, has una consulta a `TK_DT_RECORDS` con el id de `TK_CT_SERVICES_ID` y si te devuelve algo es por ya existe ese en esa tabla

Comment: Te sirvió la solución ? o como lo solucionaste ?